Failure to trigger a pipeline from the CircleCI web app as an "Org Admin"
I am the only user in the organization, and I have an "Org Admin" role. I get the following error when I try to manually trigger a pipeline from the CircleCI web app.

no suitable credential could be found for user

I can select a pipeline config, but that's about it. I'm using GitHub and my workflow runs automatically when I push to main.


Did you originally integrate with the CircleCI OAuth app and then add a pipeline with the new Github App? In my case I could start a pipeline but other users got that error. I asked CircleCI and this is what they said:

This is a known issue we're working on. The solution at the moment is to have each user go into Project Settings > Add Pipeline > Authorize. [...] We're working on making this more clear in the web app in the coming weeks and having a better solution other than going to Project Settings to click the "Authorize" button.


I needed to create a new pipeline(although there was a default pipeline), and it's "Project Settings > Pipelines > Add Pipeline > Authorize."
